# How to connect to a MySQL Docker Container via SSH?

Tags: mysql, docker, ssh, docker-compose

When I try to tunnel via SSH to the Host Mashine (vServer) and then try to connect via the internal docker Container-IP then I can't connect to MySQL.

This is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    build: ./mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
```

The only solution I found was to forward the MySQL-Port of the mysql container to the Host-Mashine.

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    build: ./mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
   ports:
     - 3306:3306
```

Then I am able to connect via the Host IP to MySQL but this is without SSH its direct via TCP and the port.
This is a No-Go for me to bring the MySQL Service into the internet.

Reasons can be found here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63881/is-it-not-safe-to-open-mysqls-port-to-the-internet why it is not a good practice to bring your mysql port into the internet.

---

So what is a good practice to connect to my docker mysql container with SSH but keep the mysql ports closed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One simple way is to bind the MySQL port only to the localhost address. That assumes the host has a mysql client available outside of Docker.

```
ports:
  - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
```

You could also omit the `ports` section completely (no port binding at all), and use the mysql client that's already inside the container.

```
docker-compose exec mysql bash
```

Then run the `mysql` command inside the container to do whatever queries you want to do.

Comment: The first suggestion fixed it for me, now I am able to connect via HeidiSQL via SSH to my MySQL-Container without a lot effort. Your second suggestion is good for small things but I like my GUI HeidiSQL.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to achieve this is to forward the ssh port of the docker conatiner to some port on your host, i.e.

```
ports:
   - 22:<some free host port>
```

and then access the container via ssh to the host port you used. Note, that it is a bad idea to use port 22, since that will cause a conflict with the ssh server running on your host.

Comment: This is a good answer as well but its a bit overkill for my purpose at the moment. Then I have to dockerize the ssh service and make it accessible to other containers. At first I will stay with Dan Lowe's answer but when the project get's bigger your answer is maybe the way to go.

Comment: There is no need to dockerize ssh. You can simply access the Container via `ssh localhost:<some free port>`

Comment: @TobiasGuggenmos Only if the sshd server is listening inside the container, which is not the case in most containers.